# Dynamic server side creation of tiles for leaflet map

Tags: php, maps, leaflet, tile

I need to display +-250 jpeg images (which are maps with no georeference). each jpeg is about 7Mb in filesize. When I make tiles from a jpeg with maptiler the total tile structure increases to 40Mb. I don't like this because I don't have that much space on the server. I wonder if there will be a significant decrease in performance if I create the tiles on demand with php (i.e. create and serve them when needed). Of course it will make the server work harder but will it be that bad?

Answer (score 0):

There will be quite a decrease in performance if you move this server-side and do it in PHP. Really the best option would be to get more server space or use something like [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to host the images, that would be able to do it cheaply and simply.